# Create conditional to check if raster has value

Tags: arcpy, raster-conversion, conditional

I have a problem with this code:

```
ac = ExtractByMask(raster, "area.shp")
arcpy.RasterToPoint_conversion(ac, "point.shp", "VALUE")
```

The problem is that sometimes the raster has no value. 
(It's a flow accumulation and the precision of my raster is not enough for what I am asking but that's not the point). 
So the RasterToPoint can't work.

So my question is:
How can I make a condition like: `"if my raster has no value, don't do the RasterToPoint"`

Comment: Can you calculate your NULL values to an ambiguous value, such as -1 or even 0?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are several ways to incorporate raster properties into a conditional statement.  Here are three methods:

```
import arcpy, os, numpy

ras = r"C:\path\to\raster.tif"

# Method 1 Using Spatial Analyst
if arcpy.sa.Raster(ras).maximum > 0:
    arcpy.RasterToPoint_conversion(ras, r"C:\temp\out.shp", "VALUE")

# Method 2 using the raster properties
if arcpy.GetRasterProperties_management(ras, "MAXIMUM").getOutput(0) > 0:
    arcpy.RasterToPoint_conversion(ras, r"C:\temp\out.shp", "VALUE")

# Method 3 Describing the raster via a numpy array
array = arcpy.RasterToNumPyArray(ras)

if numpy.max(array) > 0:
    arcpy.RasterToPoint_conversion(ras, r"C:\temp\out.shp", "VALUE")
```

Comment: You could also use the allnodata parameter in the raster properties tool to return if the raster has all no data cells.

Comment: It is possible a raster has all negative values, which would cause that raster to be skipped in the conversion to point.