# Writing Python script tool to enable ModelBuilder to skip over rasters without data?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, modelbuilder, python-script-tool

This modelbuilder [image]works well until the raster to polygon step. At that step, rasters without features cause an error(error 010151). I would like to put in a step before raster to polygon that causes the model to skip over these "feature-less" rasters. I have very little experience with python and rasters and need some help. I tried to make a row count sequence but it didn't work because the rasters did not have a table to check.

Answer (score 1):

I shall caveat my answer with the warning that I have little modelbuilder experience, but here's what I've been able to figure out.

I found [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/113234/create-conditional-to-check-if-raster-has-value), and for me the third method worked best for determining if a raster has values in it.

I created a `.py` file and added this code:

```
import arcpy
import numpy

ras = arcpy.GetParameterAsText (0)
array = arcpy.RasterToNumPyArray(ras)

if numpy.max(array) > 0:
    arcpy.SetParameterAsText (1, ras)

else:
    arcpy.SetParameterAsText (1, "")
    arcpy.SetParameterAsText (2, "True")
```

I then created a custom ArcGIS toolbox and added my script:

[image: Add Script]

I added some basic properties:

[image: Python tool properties 1]

I added the path to the python file:

[image: Add python file path]

I set the parameter properties as below. Make sure `Has Values` and `Has No Values` have their direction set to `Output`:

[image: Set parameter properties]

I was then able to incorporate the script into model builder by drag/dropping it:

[image]

If the raster has values, the Has Values output will be a string of the path to the raster. If not, it will be an empty string.