# Skip empty rasters in ArcGIS

Tags: arcpy, raster, modelbuilder, if-else

I'm trying to write some code to skip over empty raster sets when converting rasters to point (the empty sets stop the conversion, leaving me with a half complete model run).

I know that I can identify empty rasters using the ALLNODATA result from "Get Raster Properties" [Create conditional to check if raster has value](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/113234/create-conditional-to-check-if-raster-has-value).

I know I can delete rasters using the Delete.management tool.

I know I should be able to create a branch using calculate value.

But I'm inexperienced with python and modelbuilder, and haven't been able to put this all together. Could someone help me figure out what I am doing wrong? My code and an image of the modelbuilder setup are below.

```
def fn(Property):

#Import modules
     import arcpy

#ifelse statement
if Property == "1": 
           return "true"
elif Property == "0":
           return "false"
```

[image: ModelBuilderEx]

Comment: Try taking the second argument (Layer) out of Delete_management.  What error are you getting and where does it happen in the process?

Comment: Please define "empty set". What if a raster contains only a single value (e.g. 1)? Would this qualify as an empty raster?

Comment: Cross-posted as http://stackoverflow.com/q/39127665/820534

Answer (score 1):

Here is one approach that utilizes [`numpy.unique()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) to find all the unique raster values. Essentially, if there is greater than 1 value in the raster, do something, else pass. You can easily alter the logic to look for specific values, or no values, if you prefer.

```
import arcpy, os
import numpy as np

raster = r'C:\path\to\singleband\raster.tif'

array = arcpy.RasterToNumPyArray(raster)

values = np.unique(array)

# Check to make sure there are more than 1 value in raster
if values > 1:
    print "There are two or more values"
    # Do something...
```